# select spacific sheet in import data from Excel to database ADO.net using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I need to select Sheet Name When I import data from Excel To Database using ADO.net in C# that is how i Import Excel File put i can't select sheet name

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
                op.Filter = "Excel Workbook| *.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
                if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    return;
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(op.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                IExcelDataReader excelreader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                DataSet result = excelreader.AsDataSet();
```

How can I select the name of the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source code from that library you're using:

```
    public System.Data.DataSet AsDataSet(bool convertOADateTime)
    {
        if (!_isValid) return null;

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        for (int ind = 0; ind < _workbook.Sheets.Count; ind++)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable(_workbook.Sheets[ind].Name);

//table filling code snipped

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                dataset.Tables.Add(table);
            table.EndLoadData();
        }
        dataset.AcceptChanges();
        Helpers.FixDataTypes(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
```

It looks to me like that dataset it produces has N number of DataTable objects inside, each one has a table name of whatever name was given to the sheet when the constructor was called: `new DataTable(_workbook.Sheets[ind].Name);`

You called your DataSet `result`. This code would hence list out the names of the tables inside of your dataset:

```
foreach(DataTable dt in result.Tables)
  Console.Out.WriteLine(dt.TableName);
```

Comment: i don't want the name of table ,i have 3 sheets in Excel i want to take the data in sheet 3 not 1

Comment: So when you said "How can I select the name of the sheet" you didn't want to know the name of the sheet? Clearly my mind reading skills aren't what they were...  If you want data from the third sheet in the workbook, it's probably in `result.Tables[2]`. Run your code, pause it in the debugger on the line AFTER `DataSet result = excelreader.AsDataSet();` and then point to `result` with the mouse. Click the magnifying glass icon that appears...